# Cancel accounts someone else created using my email address

Tags: united-states, email

I have somebody that uses my email address to sign up for many services.

Often I get an order confirmation email with this person's actual street address, or other more private pieces of information, which is really scary.

Is there any legal problem with me logging in to the 3rd party services and canceling the accounts? When online services are concerned it seems that the email address is the more certain way to uniquely identify users, but I fear that some of these services, especially those that have this other person's credit card information, could actually consider this a "hack" into account access.

I have no intention to maliciously login as them and make additional purchases or to steal their personal information (even though I know much more than I want to know about this person already thanks to the frequent emails).

Would I be within my legal right to close down these accounts?

Comment: There is a somewhat similar question that is more generic than this one. My question is asking specifically about closing down accounts. Here is the link to the other question if anyone is interested, as an answer to that question would be helpful as well (as of yet it has not been answered)
http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/what-should-i-do-if-someone-signs-up-for-an-account-using-my-email-address Thanks!

Comment: On the flip side.. someone gave out my cell # at some check cashing place and as a result I've been inundated with telemarketing calls for him. I'd love to take some action against that individual :)